# Clustered Bar Chart with Two Colors

Tags: excel, powerbi, dashboard, kpi

I want to create the below chart :

[image]

Expectation : I want to show the two colors like in above image. one for Actual Percentage and second for total ( like 100%).

My chart look like below :

[image]

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create another value to add to your stacked chart. Just create another cell in your data, using a formula such as "=100-actual". The actual will be a reference to your cell with your value of 49.47.

Then create a chart on both numbers. If you don't want the cell visible, just change the text to match your background.

Comment: Another Solution for this scenarios is : 
Create an rectangular according to 100% percentage. and then place you chart on the rectangular shape accordingly. It works.